# Exclude category from get_category_parents (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm looking for a way to exclude categories with ID 3 and 4 from get_category_parents of my breadcrumb theme. This is the code, The line in question is the 11:

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
global $post;
if (!is_home()) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_option('home').'">'.home.'</a>';
    if (is_category()) {
        echo " / ";
        echo single_cat_title();
    } elseif(is_single() && !is_attachment()) {
        $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
        echo " / ";
        echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
        echo " / ";
        echo thman_get_limited_string($post->post_title,30);
    }       
    elseif (is_search()) {
        echo " / " . cerca;
    }       
    elseif (is_page() && $post->post_parent) {
        echo ' / <a href="'.get_permalink($post->post_parent).'">';
        echo get_the_title($post->post_parent);
        echo "</a> / ";
        echo thman_get_limited_string($post->post_title,30);        
    }
    elseif (is_page() OR is_attachment()) {
        echo " / "; 
        echo thman_get_limited_string($post->post_title,30);
    }
    elseif (is_author()) {
        echo wp_title(' / Profilo');
        echo "";
    }
    elseif (is_404()) {
        echo " / "; 
        echo errore_404;
    }       
    elseif (is_archive()) {
        echo wp_title(' / ');       
    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$cat = get_the_category();
$cat = $cat[0]->term_id;
// next will return an array of all category ancestors, with toplevel cat being [0]
$ancestors = array_reverse(get_ancestors($cat, 'category'));
if($ancestors) {
  // set up output
  $output = '';
  foreach($ancestors as $cat) {
    // skips cats 3 and 4
    if($cat == '3' || $cat == '4') continue;
    $catlink = get_category_link($cat);
    $catname = get_cat_name($cat);
    $output .= '<a href="' . $catlink . '">' . $catname . '</a>' . "\n";
  }
}

echo $output;
```

That's off the top of my head, but I believe it's correct.

Comment: +1...Excellent answer Shelly! This should most definitely get the job done!

Comment: thanks shelly the answer, but I'm not an expert in php, so my full code should be like the one below?

Comment: Okay - pardon me - I'm sort of a n00b on these forums :) I can't find the "comment" link to comment on your question below!  But yes, the code I gave you should replace the stuff that's in the "elseif(is_single() && !is_attachment()) {" section - and I believe that's what you have below.  Again, that code is off the top of my head, so you might have to play with it a bit - but I think it's correct. Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks shelly, but gives me error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' to this location $ancestors = array_reverse(get_ancestors($cat, 'category');

Comment: ok missed a parenthesis $ancestors = array_reverse(get_ancestors($cat, 'category')); but now the error is as follows Fatal error: Call to undefined function get ancestors()

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running? get_ancestors is definitely there - it's a new function, put in in version 3.1.x.  If you're not running that version, then you'll need to upgrade (which you should do anyway - not just for this function.)

Comment: Thank you for your patience Selly. I upgraded to wordpress 3.1, but now I receive this error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() It refers to this piece of code: foreach($ancestor as $cat) {

Comment: Mispelling. it should be "foreach($ancestors as $cat)" - it's missing an "s".

Comment: ok I do not get any error but does not work ..... Sally thank you anyway you are very kind but I give up

Comment: OP: Could you fix the two syntax errors? The variable in the foreach is missing the "s" ($ancestors) and a missing closing parenthesis for array_reverse.

Answer (score 0):

thanks shelly the answer, but I'm not an expert in php, so my full code should look like this?

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
global $post;
if (!is_home()) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_option('home').'">'.home.'</a>';
    if (is_category()) {
        echo " / ";
        echo single_cat_title();
    } elseif(is_single() && !is_attachment()) {
      $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0]->term_id;
  // next will return an array of all category ancestors, with toplevel cat being [0]
  $ancestors = array_reverse(get_ancestors($cat, 'category');
  if($ancestors) {
  // set up output
  $output = '';
  foreach($ancestor as $cat) {
  // skips cats 3 and 4
  if($cat == '3' || $cat == '4') continue;
  $catlink = get_category_link($cat);
  $catname = get_cat_name($cat);
  $output .= '<a href="' . $catlink . '">' . $catname . '</a>' . "\n";
   }
  }
  echo $output;
        echo " / ";
        echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
        echo " / ";
        echo the_title_shorten(45,'...');
    }       
    elseif (is_search()) {
        echo " / " . cerca;
    }       
    elseif (is_page() && $post->post_parent) {
        echo ' / <a href="'.get_permalink($post->post_parent).'">';
        echo get_the_title($post->post_parent);
        echo "</a> / ";
        echo the_title_shorten(45,'...');       
    }
    elseif (is_page() OR is_attachment()) {
        echo " / "; 
        echo the_title_shorten(45,'...');
    }
    elseif (is_author()) {
        echo wp_title(' / Profilo');
        echo "";
    }
    elseif (is_404()) {
        echo " / "; 
        echo errore_404;
    }       
    elseif (is_archive()) {
        echo wp_title(' / ');       
    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of you,
I finally get the code working:

```
$ancestors = array_reverse(get_ancestors(get_cat_ID(single_cat_title("", false)), 'category'));
$cat_parent_and_cat = '';
if($ancestors) {
    foreach($ancestors as $cat) {               
         //if($cat == '3' || $cat == '4') continue; // skips cats 3 and 4
         $catlink = get_category_link($cat);
         $catname = get_cat_name($cat);
         $cat_parent_and_cat .= '<a href="' . $catlink . '">' . $catname . '</a>' . ' &rsaquo; ' ;
    }
}
echo $cat_parent_and_cat;
```

Hope it will help someone